# Div in navbar Bootstrap break the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I have a navbar which is centered perfectly with this code :

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary navbar-personalized w-100 justify-content-center navbar-personalized">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                My WebSite
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Now I want to add a div inside which is clickable :

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary w-100 justify-content-center navbar-personalized">
      <div class="row">
        <a class="navbar-brand">
          My Web Site
        </a>

          <div id="messageAdministrateur" onclick="alert('This is an alert')" style="color:red;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
          <b>WARNING, NEW MESSAGE<br>CLICK</b>
          </div>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

I would like to center the both but only `WARNING, NEW MESSAGE CLICK` is centered and not `My Web Site`. How to center the both ? This is a working example :
https://jsfiddle.net/g2ea36rn/

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create columns after rows. So just add for each div a col-12 and style the text centered.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
  My Web Site
</a>

  <div id="messageAdministrateur" onclick="alert('This is an alert')" style="color:red;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
  <center><b>WARNING, NEWdd MESSAGE</b></center><b><center>CLICK</b></center>
  </div>
     </div>
    </div>


.navbar-personalized{
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add below styling on the `div` after your `nav`. Here you can use `flex` to justify your content to the center. And to have it in the center of the screen set `width` to `100%`

```
style="display:flex; justify-content:center; width:100%"
```

```js
.navbar - personalized {
  position: absolute!important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0 px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="My WebSite">
  <link rel="icon" href="ressources/favicon.ico" />
  <title>My WebSite</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>

  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div >
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary w-100  navbar-personalized">
        <div class="row" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; width:100%">
          <a class="navbar-brand">
              My Web Site
            </a>

          <div id="messageAdministrateur" onclick="alert('This is an alert')" style="color:red;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
            <center><b>WARNING, NEW MESSAGE</b></center><b>
                <center>CLICK
              </b></center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ex dolor, malesuada vitae semper a, imperdiet eu sapien. Aenean volutpat congue mi, eu consequat nisl maximus nec. Suspendisse pharetra suscipit lorem a iaculis. Duis efficitur libero vitae purus
        interdum viverra quis nec est. Ut et ante et justo posuere hendrerit. Ut eu mauris at mi egestas rhoncus non vitae magna. Etiam a vehicula nisl, vel convallis lacus. Sed at urna sit amet enim tempor condimentum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
        magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```